# Distributed Transaction Error Only Through Code

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, linked-server

I and trying to perform a query against a linked server (SQL Server 2008 linked to Sybase) and select it into a temp table.  Is works perfectly though a query window in SQL Management Studio, but when I do it through code (C#) it fails with the error "The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "ASEOLEDB" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction. I am not using a transaction in code with my DbConnection.

This query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temptable
FROM OPENQUERY([MYLINKEDSERVER], 'SELECT * from table')
```

Comment: Is MSDTC configured the same for all machines involved in the distributed transaction? Are the [permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/03/13/troubleshooting-msdtc-permission-issues-when-a-distributed-transaction-starts.aspx) all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  It was a result of connection pooling.  It appears that connections were getting reused causing the system to think there was a distributed transaction happening.